# Excel convert table into multiple columns as raw data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I transform this table into multiple columns without using Power Query

I want to write a function in a cell
So that multiple combinations after removing duplicates can appear.

1. Original rable with duplicated header:

[image]

2. Covert into a column without duplicated header.

[image]

I was thinking of trying to use the `UNIQUE()` function to remove duplicate headers from both rows and columns, and then transform it into various combinations

Answer (score 0):

You may try-

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A6&"|"&B1:F1)),
LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(x,"|")))),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun,
thanks for ur help
it seems failed
it shows #NAME?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way without using `LAMBDA()` helper functions:

[image]

---

```
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(B2:F6,A2:A6),2),TOCOL(IFS(B2:F6,B1:F1),2)))
```

---

Or,

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(B2:F6,A2:A6&"|"&B1:F1))),"|",{1,2}),"|")
```

---

Or, if no conditions to check:

```
=UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&TOCOL(A2:A6&"|"&B1:F1),"|",{1,2}),"|"))
```

---

Or it could be more simpler as based on the data in the OP:

```
=MID(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A6&" "&B1:F1)),{1,4},{2,2})
```

---

Alternatively, if one don't have access to `TOCOL()` then:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, UNIQUE(A2:A6)&"|"&UNIQUE(B1:F1,1),
     _Rows, INT((SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Data)*COLUMNS(_Data))-1)/COLUMNS(_Data))+1,
     _Columns, MOD((SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Data)*COLUMNS(_Data))-1),COLUMNS(_Data))+1,
     MID(INDEX(_Data,_Rows,_Columns),{1,4},{2,2}))
```

---

Or, If the `LEN()` is not defined.

```
=LET(
     _Data, UNIQUE(A2:A6)&"|"&UNIQUE(B1:F1,1),
     _Rows, INT((SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Data)*COLUMNS(_Data))-1)/COLUMNS(_Data))+1,
     _Columns, MOD((SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Data)*COLUMNS(_Data))-1),COLUMNS(_Data))+1,
     _Transformed, INDEX(_Data,_Rows,_Columns),
     CHOOSE({1,2},
     LEFT(_Transformed,LEN(_Transformed)-FIND("|",_Transformed)),
     RIGHT(_Transformed,LEN(_Transformed)-FIND("|",_Transformed))))
```

---

Or bit shorter using `FILTERXML()` but this won't work on `Excel For Web` :

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:A6&"|"&B1:F1,
     _Transformed, FILTERXML("<m><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",TRUE,_Data)&"</b></m>","//b"),
     _Answer, MID(UNIQUE(_Transformed),{1,4},{2,2}),
     _Answer)
```

---

Comment: Hi Mayukh,
thanks for ur help
i tried without using LAMBDA()
but it also shows #NAME?

Comment: @Chiao-lingWang I have updated with few more alternatives try those as per your suit. Also what is your excel version may i know?

Comment: Hi Mayukh, really appreciate your response, I tried but still showed #NAME?
and my Excel version is 16.18 (181014) or should i use google sheet?

Comment: @Chiao-lingWang so you are using `Excel For MAC` version 2019` is that so?

Comment: Hi Mayukh, yes i use mac and excel version 2019